# Delete posts after a certain time, even when user isn't using the app

Tags: ios, firebase, timer, swift3

I'm using Swift on iOS and Firebase

I am trying to find a way to delete a post when it was shared more than X hours ago, no matter if the user is connected on the app, or not.

For that I have set a time stamp for my post object, which gives the  date/time when the post is initially created.

I thought about adding a "timer" to my post node, that would be updated every second. The problem with that is that I would need for that to make a request to my database every second, and this would obviously be very data consuming.

I googled a lot and it seems like the only way of doing this is using some server-side code in Javascript using Google Functions, and I read the documentation but I still have no idea how I can do that and can't barely find anything refering to it.

Do you have an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are not concerned about the amount of "stale" posts, why not simply filter them by your timestamp and delete them as soon as your app is active again?

Comment: Hi @Filburt ! Thanks for your answer :) Unfortunately yeah that's why I was wondering how to do that with google functions. but indeed that would be one of the possibility. Just one question though, when would you triger that ? Do you have to do it every single second ? Because of the user is connected and stays watching the timeline, the view is already loaded so it won't update the list anymore and the child added won't be called. In such a situation how can I be sure at that time that the post reached is expiration time?

Comment: I'd love to help but I'm afraid this is way above my head. I'll have to leave it to the Firebase pros if my suggestion is even technically possible.

Comment: No problem ! Thanks again for your reply, and I'm gonna wait for some more answers then !